# Wightman QFTs corresponding to Minimal Models

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, conformal-field-theory

Per suggestion, I am cross-posting the following question from MathOverflow [(original)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407058/wightman-qfts-corresponding-to-minimal-models). At MO, Abdesselam referenced the work [2]. Glancing through it, is not immediately obvious to  me how far the work therein gets us along a mathematical construction (in the spirit of the Glimm-Jaffe school) of say the Wightman QFT corresponding to $\mathcal{M}(4,3)$. So as an addendum to the original question below: (1) how far does it get us? (2) concretely, how could one use the ideas of [2] to prove that the $S_N$ below satisfy reflection positivity?

Is it known (rigorously) whether or not there exist (1+1)D Wightman QFTs which can (in some reasonable sense) be said to correspond to physicists' unitary minimal models $\mathcal{M}(m+1,m)$, $m\in\mathbb{N}^+$, $m\geq 3$?

For example, the case $m=3$ is supposed to model the continuum 2D Ising model at criticality [[1](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-2256-9)], and it seems that based on some heuristics physicists have conjectured  -- or proven, at a level of rigor acceptable to them -- that the Schwinger functions of such a QFT should be
$$ S_N(z_1,\cdots,z_N) = \Big[\sum_{\substack{\varsigma_1,\ldots,\varsigma_N \in \{-1,+1\}\\ \varsigma_1+\cdots+\varsigma_N=0}} \prod_{1\leq m<n\leq N} |z_m-z_n|^{\varsigma_m\varsigma_n/2} \Big]^{1/2},$$
$z_1,\ldots,z_N\in \mathbb{R}^2$ pairwise distinct. See Section 12.3.3 of [1]. (Moreover, some aspects of this have been rigorously proven. See the answer on [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144713/are-there-exactly-solvable-cfts/230973#230973).)
Since a Wightman QFT is determined by its Wightman functions, and since its Wightman functions are determined via analytic continuation by its Schwinger functions, I would expect that the sequence $\{S_N\}_{N=0}^\infty$ uniquely specifies a Wightman QFT. Since one can analytically continue $S_N$ back to ``real time'' by hand, I would further expect that to construct such a QFT it suffices to check that the $S_N$ satisfy the original Osterwalder-Schrader axioms, of which the trickiest seems to be reflection positivity (/Wightman positivity after analytic continuation). Hence, I would expect that a necessary and sufficient condition for there to exist a Wightman QFT whose Schwinger functions are the $S_N$ is that they satisfy reflection positivity, but this (if true) seems non-obvious to me.

[[1]](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-2256-9) Francesco, Mathieu, and Senechal, *Conformal Field Theory*, Chapters 7, 12

[[2]](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FJHEP08%282021%29094) Kravchuk, Qiao, Rychkov, *Distributions in CFT: Part II. Minkowski Space*

Comment: I think that the main non-trivial observations of our work are not particularly useful for your question because they mainly relate to the question of whether the analytically-continued Schwinger functions satisfy powerlaw bounds which suffice to establish temperedness of Wightman correlators. For minimal model Schwinger functions this is straightforward from the explicit expressions.

Comment: The simpler observation in our paper is that if you can prove a sufficiently strong OPE for Schwinger functions, you can also prove reflection-positivity using reality conditions on OPE coefficients and unitarity of representations of the conformal group. However, we only worked it out for 4-point correlators and global conformal algebra. I'd expect that for Virasoro minimal models, using Virasoro symmetry, one should be able to give a proof for all Schwinger functions, since OPEs contain finitely-many terms.

Comment: I wonder if one can show the OPE as a conclusion from the above explicit formula, rather than a hypothesis, which is the reverse of the logic followed by CFT textbooks (e.g., the yellow one). A priori, from the explicit formula you can iteratively take asymptotic expansions where z1 goes to z2. This will generate new fields and new correlations and one may be able to prove the OPE structure that way.

Comment: @Peter When you say "finitely many terms," you mean finitely many conformal families right? (Because each conformal family should generically bring in infinitely many descendants in each OPE.) Should it be obvious that the descendant coefficients one defines in terms of the primary coefficients decay fast enough that there are no convergence issues in the sum over descendants?

Comment: @EthanSussman Yes. Each conformal family contributes to the correlator a special function which called "conformal block", and I meant that there are finitely many Virasoro conformal blocks that contribute. What is proven about Virasoro conformal blocks at the mathematical level of rigor is a tough question, but certainly a lot is understood about their structure and properties.